# Richness of the subgroup structure of p-groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Given a prime $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_p(n)$ be the smallest
number such that there is a group of order $p^{f_p(n)}$ which all groups of
order $p^n$ embed into. What is the asymptotic growth of $f_p(n)$ when
$n$ tends to infinity?

The question asks in a certain sense for how dense $p$-groups can be "packed together"
as subgroups of a larger group.

Let's give an example for illustration: By the bound by Francois Brunault, all groups of
order $2^{20}$ embed into a group of order $2^{2^{20}-1}$, which is a number with
315653 decimal digits. On the other hand, by Nick Gill's bound, they do not embed
into a group of order $2^{66}$, which is a 20-digit number.
Can these bounds be refined?

**Added on Feb 21, 2013:** Even if finding precise asymptotics for $f_p(n)$ turns out to be
delicate, isn't it at least possible to decide whether $f_p(n)$ grows polynomially or
exponentially, or whether its growth rate lies somewhere in between?
Or alternatively, are there reasons to believe that this is a difficult problem?

**Added on Dec 4, 2013:** The question whether it is true that $f_p(n)$ grows faster than polynomially but slower than exponentially when $n$ tends to infinity will appear as Problem 18.51 in:

Kourovka Notebook: *Unsolved Problems in Group Theory*. Editors V. D.
Mazurov, E. I. Khukhro. 18th Edition, Novosibirsk 2014.

Comment: All groups of order $p^n$ embed into the symmetric group on $p^n$ letters, whose p-Sylows have size $p^f$ with $f=v_p((p^n)!)$, which gives $f_p(n) \leq (p^n-1)/(p-1)$.

Comment: Right. -- Now the growth can still be anything from linear to exponential.


Comment: I think you can rule out linear growth just by looking at abelian p-groups. I think the smallest group that will contain all such abelians is a direct product of cyclics of orders $p^n,p^{n/2},p^{n/3},p^{n/4}$,.... (you should take the floor of exponents of course). But now the size of this group is $p$ raised to $n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ and since that sum doesn't converge you can't have linear growth. Is that reasonable?

Comment: Right. -- So now $f_p(n)$ is at least $O(n \cdot \ln{n})$ and at most
$O(p^{n-1})$. Still a wide range.

Comment: Stefan, I reckon a good way to get a better upper bound would be to consider (faithful) linear representations of $p$-groups over a field of char $p$. I guess there should be a result saying that every $p$-group of order $p^n$ admits such a representation of degree $\leq x$ where $x$ is God-knows-what. If such a result exists then the next tricky thing would be to show that such a representation can be realised over a finite field of bounded size...

Comment: But an irreducible representation of a $p$-group over a field of characteristic $p$ is trivial.

Comment: @Tobias, why is this a problem? So a faithful rep can't be irreducible - but we don't need irreducibility...

Comment: @Nick Ahh, I read irreducible for some reason.

Comment: @Nick: I also guess so, and have added the tag rt.representation-theory since I think it is quite likely that someone knowledgeable on modular representation theory may say more.


Comment: The number of groups of order $p^n$ is $p^{\Theta(n^3)}$. A group of order $p^m$ can contain at most $p^{mn}$ groups of order $p^n$, since each is generated by at most $n$ elements. Thus $f_p(n)$ is at least $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Indeed. -- Now we know that $f_p(n)$ is at least $O(n^2)$ and at most $O(p^n)$.

Comment: The notion of essential dimension of a finite group might be relevant, see Karpenko-Merkurjev, Invent. math. 172, 491–508 (2008). Over ${\bf C}$ the essential dimension of groups of order $p^n$ can be exponential in $n$, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.0637.pdf but I don't know what happens in characteristic $p$. In fact the examples given there with large essential dimension are Heisenberg-like groups thus admit small faithful representations in char $p$.

Comment: Did you try calculating $f_p(n)$ for small $n$ like $2$, $3$ or $4$? Maybe you can improve François' bound slightly by combining these results with the fact that every extension $G$ of a group $N$ by a group $H$ (i.e., $G/N = H$ for some embedding of $N$ into $G$) is a subgroup of the wreath product of $N$ by $H$.

Comment: The cyclic group of order $p^n$ has a faithful representation of degree $p^{n-1}+1$ in char $p$, but of no smaller degree. The reason is that a matrix of order $p^n$ in char $p$ has the form $1+N$, where $N$ is nilpotent, but $N^{p^{n-1}}\neq 0$. It follows that the God-knows-what-$x$ form Nick Gill's comment is at least $p^{n-1}+1$. So modular representation theory will not be of much help, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Someone: I think the sheer size of the wreath product renders this 
approach useless -- if the groups $N$ and $H$ have both order $p^n$, 
their standard wreath product has order $p^{n(p^n+1)}$.


Comment: @StefanKohl: Yes, taking $H$ bigger than $Z_p$ doesn't give any improvements. But starting with $n=2$ and $f_p(2)=3$ you can get per induction with $H = Z_p$ upper bounds $f_p(n)\le 3p^{n-2}+(p^{n-2}-1)/(p-1)$. For odd $p$ I get with $f_p(3)=5$ an upper bound of type $O(p^{n-3})$.

Comment: As $n$ is the variable here, we have $O(p^{n-3}) = O(p^n)$.
So asymptotically we don't gain anything.


Answer (score 2):

The comment by Frieder Ladisch suggests to me that considering exponents may be relevant. Suppose that we generalize Stefan Kohl's function
$f_p(n)$ as follows:

**Definition:** Fix a prime $p$ and an exponent $e$. Let $F(p,e,n)$ be the smallest integer such that there is a group of order $p^{F(p,e,n)}$ which contains
isomorphic copies of every group of order $p^n$ and exponent $p^e$.

**Lemma:** Then $\max_{1\leq e\leq n} F(p,e,n)\leq f_p(n)\leq \sum_{e=1}^n F(p,e,n)$ for all $n\geq1$ and all primes $p$.

**Proof:** The upper bound is obtained by considering direct products, and the lower bound is easy.

Clearly $F(p,n,n)=n$ and $F(2,1,n)=n$ as a group order $p^n$ and exponent $p^e$ is cyclic if $n=e$, and is elementary abelian if $p=2$ and $e=1$. A very wild guess is that the asymptotic size of $f_p(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ is governed by $F(p,1,n)$ for $p>2$, and $F(2,2,n)$ for $p=2$.

It is unclear to me how helpful wreath products are. Suppose that
$G(p,e,n)$ is a $p$-group that contains isomorphic copies of every group of order
$p^n$ and exponent $p^e$. I claim (without proof) that the $p$-group $G(p,e_2,n_2)\;{\rm wr}\;G(p,e_1,n_1)$ contains isomorphic copies of every group of order
$p^{n_1+n_2}$ and exponent $p^{e_1+e_2}$. This gives the upper-bound $$F(p,e_1+e_2,n_1+n_2)\leq F(p,e_2,n_2)p^{F(p,\,e_1,\,n_1)}+F(p,e_1,n_1).$$
In terms of the previous discussion, a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^e}$ or ${\rm GL}(e+1,p)$ has exponent $e$.

Comment: Am I right that your upper bound on $F(p,2e,2n)$ is larger than
$p^{F(p,e,n)}$? -- If so, I think this gives hardly an improvement
to what we already know.

Comment: The claim by Frieder that "modular representation theory will not be of much help" may not be correct because Nick Gill's dimension $x$ now depends on the exponent $e$. You are right that the wreath product bound is weak.

Answer (score 0):

Each finite $p$-group $H$ may be embedded in the Frattini subgroup of an appropriate $p$-group $G$ (for example, $G=H \wr C_p$; here $d(G)\le d(H)+1$. Then for this $G$, the Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$ contains a subgroup which is isomorphic to $H$.)

Problem. Is it true that one can choose $G$ so that $d(G)=2$?

Yakov

Comment: What is the appropriate $p$-group, then? Also, please put dollar signs around your math (use the edit button).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/ask) button.
Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I am not sure what appropriate means here. However, every $p$-group can be embedded in the Nottingham group (which is $2$-generated for $p>2$). Thus, can be embedded in a finite quotient of it. I am quite sure that embedding it in the Frattini subgroup is not an issue. This will also give some answer to the original question.

Comment: If the "problem" is meant to be a Socratic question, then it would probably be less confusing if rephrased as a declarative sentence.